# Portion of poetry text not shown in html page created by xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

i'm working on the digitalization of a text, but a portion of poetry in the middle of the text is not shown, can you help me?

XSL code: http://pastebin.com/TkgZLurQ
XML code: http://pastebin.com/fyA4Ka1f

The portion of the XML file that is not transformated is:

```
<div type="poetry">
    <epigraph>
        <lg rhyme="ababcb">
            <l><name type="person">Beatrice</name> tutta ne l’etterne <rhyme label="a">rote</rhyme></l>
            <l>fissa con li occhi stava; e io in <rhyme label="b">lei</rhyme></l>
            <l>le luci fissi, di là sù <rhyme label="a">rimote</rhyme>.</l>
            <l>Nel suo aspetto tal dentro mi <rhyme label="b">fei</rhyme>,</l>
            <l>qual si fé <name type="person">Glauco</name> nel gustar de l’<rhyme label="c">erba</rhyme></l>
            <l>che ’l fé consorto in mar de li altri <rhyme label="b">dèi</rhyme>.</l>
        </lg>
    </epigraph>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a template `<xsl:template match="tei:body/tei:div[@type='racconto']/tei:div[@type='poetry']">` and a template `<xsl:template match="tei:body/tei:div[@type='racconto']">` but the latter does not use `apply-templates` so the former template is never applied. Your whole approach is wrong, don't use `for-each` inside of matching templates to process some child elements, instead use `apply-templates` and write templates for the the child elements.

And you can save yourself some typing by using literal result elements like `<div>..</div>` instead of `<xsl:element name="div">...</xsl:element>`.

So instead of

```
<xsl:template match="tei:body/tei:div[@type='poetry']">
    <xsl:element name="div">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">poetry</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="tei:epigraph/tei:lg/tei:l">
            <xsl:element name="p">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">poetry</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:element name="i">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

use

```
<xsl:template match="tei:body/tei:div[@type='poetry']">
    <div class="poetry">
        <!-- depending on your needs <xsl:apply-templates/> suffices, or use -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:epigraph/tei:lg/tei:l"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="tei:epigraph/tei:lg/tei:l">
  <p class="poetry">
    <i>
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </i>
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

For the `<xsl:template match="tei:body/tei:div[@type='racconto']">` you need to make sure you put `<xsl:apply-templates/>` in there to make sure child nodes are processed, as you have various stuff in there I can't tell where exactly you want it, but the general approach is as in the example above, map an element of the input to the HTML you want and then process its children with apply-templates, making sure you write templates for those elements that need output.

Comment: ok, i'm not sure i got it all XD
can you provide me an example please? My professor at University was supposed to explain us the correct approach, needless to say it did not happen...